# Chi-square statistic across multiple columns of a dataframe using dplyr or reshape2

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, broom

I have a question about using `dplyr` and `reshape2` to calculate chi-square statistics across multiple columns. Below is a small dataframe...

```
Sat <- c("Satisfied","Satisfied","Dissatisfied","Dissatisfied",
                                       "Neutral")

Gender <- c("Male","Male","Female","Male","Female")

Ethnicity <- c("Asian","White","White","Asian","White")

AgeGroup <- c("18-20","18-20","21-23","18-20","18-28")

Example <- data.frame(Sat,Gender,Ethnicity,AgeGroup)
```

How would I use `summarise_each` or `melt` to calculate the `Sat` column against each of the other variables to produce chi-square residual and p-value stats. I'm thinking there must be something like:

```
Example %>% summarise_each(funs(chisq.test(...
```

but I'm not sure how to finish it. Also, how would I melt the data frame and use `group_by` or `do()` to get the chi-square stats? I'm interested in seeing both methods. If there's a way to incorporate the `broom` package, that would be great too, or `tidyr` instead of `reshape2`.

So to recap, I would like to run chi-square tests, such as

```
chisq.test(Example$Sat, Example$Gender)
```

but...I would like to produce chi-square stats for the `Sat` variable against `Gender`, `Ethnicity`, and `AgeGroup`. This is a small example, and I'm  hoping the methods above will allow me to create chi-square stats across many columns in a fast and efficient manner. Bonus if I can plot the residuals in a heat map with `ggplot2`, which is why I'm interested in incorporating the `broom` package into this example.

Comment: There are periods in `Sat` which should probably be commas; it won't run as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to get the `p values`

```
 Example %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(chisq.test(., 
               Example$Sat)$p.value), -one_of("Sat"))
 #     Gender Ethnicity  AgeGroup
 #1 0.2326237 0.6592406 0.1545873
```

Or to extract the `statistic`

```
Example %>%
    summarise_each(funs(chisq.test(., 
           Example$Sat)$statistic), -one_of("Sat"))
#   Gender Ethnicity AgeGroup
#1 2.916667 0.8333333 6.666667
```

To get the `residuals`, it would be easier with `base R`

```
 lapply(Example[setdiff(names(Example), "Sat")], 
       function(x) chisq.test(x, Example$Sat)$residuals)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers, they work great! Just one question, I'm not familiar with "setdiff", what's the purpose of it?

Comment: @Mike The purpose of `setdiff` is to return those elements in the first vector that are not in the second vector.  In the example, it should return all those column names except the "Sat".

Comment: Hi Akrun, now that summarise_each is deprecated, i am trying to use summarise_at(,.vars = (1:4),) but i am getting thisError: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector

Comment: @Shub use `summarise_at(1:4, funs(`